# How to determine Ember Data type name from Route mixin?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am writing a `Route` mixin that needs to implement the `model` method.  However, because it is a `Mixin`, I don't know the model name to pass to `store.filter()`.  How can I determine the Ember Data model name from a Route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.  The 2nd parameter sent to the `model` function is a `transition` object.  You can find the model object type like this:

```
model: function(params, transition) {
    var type = Ember.Inflector.inflector.singularize(transition.targetName.split('.')[0]);
```

Comment: You can get target route name with this hack, but mapping this name on types list in general wouldn't work. In my mind best option is to add a param 'ModelType' with actual information. It's less error prone. Another way is to use BaseRoute, which you could extend and override model hook (calling this._super method with needed params, if you will).

Comment: @Microfed you are right, it will fail on `route`s (as opposed to `resource`s).